# Subtracting months in sql correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to subtract 3 months as so:

```
DECLARE @ReportingDate date = '6/30/2019'

SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH, -3,@reportingDate)
```

But what I get returned is '2019-03-30' when the correct end of month should be '2019-03-31'. How do I fix this?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? If it is 2016 or higher you can use the EOMONTH() function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016

Comment: The answer is correct for three months before an arbitrary date. If you always want then end of the month then a better way is to start with the first of the month. Take off two months and then take off 1 day. That will always force it to the end of the month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way is:

```
DECLARE @ReportingDate date = '6/30/2019'

SELECT  CASE
            WHEN @ReportingDate = EOMONTH(@ReportingDate) THEN  EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -3,@reportingDate))
            ELSE DATEADD(MONTH, -3,@reportingDate)
        END
```